# Captura de Pantalla en Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, studio, screenshot

Tengo el siguiente código kotlin, es un ejemplo de captura de pantalla, el código funciona bien pero me gustaría cambiarlo para que su funcionamiento se amoldara a lo que yo quiero, os digo lo que me gustaría conseguir:

1. Quiero que la captura de pantalla la haga sin pulsar ningún botón, me explico, me gustaría realizar la captura directamente al entrar en la activity sin que el usuario tuviera que pulsar ningún botón.
2. Me gustaría que me indicarais el método actual para realizar la captura ya que me sale el isDrawingCacheEnabled como deprecado y no se como se realiza ahora.
3. Finalmente me gustaría saber cual sería el método más correcto para guardar la captura en la memoria del dispositivo.

Os dejo el código.

Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private lateinit var imageView: ImageView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        imageView = binding.micaptura
        val miboton: Button = binding.miboton


        miboton.setOnClickListener {
            val mb: Bitmap = hacerCapturaView(imageView)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(mb)
        }
    }

    companion object Screenshot {

        private fun hacerCaptura(view: View): Bitmap {
            view.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
            view.buildDrawingCache(true)
            val b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.drawingCache)
            view.isDrawingCacheEnabled = false
            return b
        }

        fun hacerCapturaView(v: View): Bitmap {
            return hacerCaptura(v.rootView)
        }
    }
}
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/miboton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Hacer Captura"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/micaptura"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Saludos.

Comment: Para la primer pregunta, en vez de poner el código en el botón lo pones en el momento que inicia tu actividad. Para la segunda pregunta, [acá tienes un link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52905682/11539923) y para la tercer pregunta, "la más mejor" es la que está en la documentación oficial.